# How to check for element not in a set in Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to perform an update in Amazon DynamoDB, but only if a StringSet does not contain a specific string. Looking at the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) I saw that there exists the `contains()` function, which can be used inside the `ConditionExpression`. Then I tried this code:

```
function addLecture(event){
    const params = {
        TableName: 'lectures',
        Key: {
            'lecture_id': Number.parseInt(event.lecture_id)
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'SET numeric_attr = numeric_attr - :val ADD students :student',
        ConditionExpression: '(numeric_attr > :limit) AND (NOT contains(students, :student))',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':val': 1,
            ':limit' : 0,
            ':student' : ddb.createSet(event.student)
        },
        ReturnValues : 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }
    
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```

Anyway, if I try to perform the update, it is actually performed, even if the String is already in the StringSet.

How could I check for the absence of the String?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your condition is malformated:

`:student` resolves to `ddb.createSet(event.student)`. You should pass a string variable to `contains`, and not a string set. From the doc you pointed out:

> The operand must be a String if the attribute specified by path is a String. If the attribute specified by path is a Set, the operand must be the set's element type.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think that the docs you linked is not correct, since it doesn't refer to the `DocumentClient` class and to the `ConditionExpression`. If I try with `NOT_CONTAINS`, I receive that error: `ERROR ValidationException: Invalid ConditionExpression: Invalid function name; function: NOT_CONTAINS`. Maybe it's better to remove the answer, I don't want to downvote it cause you showed searching effort

Comment: Now I see that the docs you linked says: `Represents the selection criteria for a Query or Scan operation`, but I'm using an update operation

Comment: Indeed, it looks like `NOT_CONTAINS` is only for query, my bad. I'll update the answer, as I still think you should pass a string, and not a string set as operand to the CONTAINS function

Comment: Also that part of the answer is not correct, since the `contains` function works with a set and not with the string. Take a look at the docs I pointed in the question